# missing template arguments before

Tags: c++, linux, makefile

I have problem in compelling my code. The error message indicates "missing template arguments" in Map.h. But I do believe there is not any error in Map.h, because it is from Minisat, which is a sophistic API.  So I think it is my fault in code or in makefile. I have tried so many times, can you help me on this? Thank you so much!

```
The error message is:
Compiling: queryOrac/queryOrac.o
In file included from /home/parallels/Desktop/Incremental_Solver/core/SolverTypes.h:30:0,
                 from /home/parallels/Desktop/Incremental_Solver/core/Solver.h:28,
                 from /home/parallels/Desktop/Incremental_Solver/simp/SimpSolver.h:25,
                 from /home/parallels/Desktop/Incremental_Solver/queryOrac/queryOrac.cc:12:
/home/parallels/Desktop/Incremental_Solver/mtl/Map.h: In member function ‘uint32_t Minisat::Hash<K>::operator()(const K&) const’:
/home/parallels/Desktop/Incremental_Solver/mtl/Map.h:32:99: error: missing template arguments before ‘(’ token
 template<class K> struct Hash  { uint32_t operator()(const K& k)               const { return hash(k);  } };
                                                                                                   ^
/home/parallels/Desktop/Incremental_Solver/mtl/Map.h: In member function ‘uint32_t Minisat::DeepHash<K>::operator()(const K*) const’:
/home/parallels/Desktop/Incremental_Solver/mtl/Map.h:35:103: error: missing template arguments before ‘(’ token
 template<class K> struct DeepHash  { uint32_t operator()(const K* k)               const { return hash(*k);  } };
                                                                                                       ^
make: *** [/home/parallels/Desktop/Incremental_Solver/queryOrac/queryOrac.o] Error 1
```

The .cc file is (This file is a implementation of a .h file):

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

#include "queryOrac/queryOrac.h"
#include "incre/tools.h"
#include "incre/dict.h"
#include "simp/SimpSolver.h"
#include "utils/System.h"
#include "utils/ParseUtils.h"
#include "utils/Options.h"
#include "core/Dimacs.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace Minisat;
using namespace Incre;

Oracle::Oracle(const char * ora, const char * PI, const char * PO)
{
    cout << "a Oracle is created" << endl;
    PI_path = PI;
    PO_path = PO;
    Orac_Path = ora;
}

void Oracle::process()
{
    parse_PI();
    assign_PI();
    solve();
}

void Oracle::parse_PI() {
    cout << "reading from " << PI_path << endl;
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open(PI_path, ios::in);
    string first_line;
    string second_line;

    getline(infile, first_line);
    getline(infile, second_line);

    vector<string> name_temp;
    vector<string> value_temp;
    SplitString(first_line, name_temp, " ");
    SplitString(second_line, value_temp, " ");

    vector<string>::iterator value = value_temp.begin();
    for(vector<string>::iterator name = name_temp.begin(); name != name_temp.end(); ++name)
    {
        PI_temp.insert(pair<int, string>(varIndexDict[*name], *value));
        value++;
    }
}

void Oracle::assign_PI(){
    vector<int>::iterator position = pisIndex.begin();
    for(map<int, string>::iterator index = PI_temp.begin(); index != PI_temp.end(); ++index)
    {
        if(index->second == "1") PI_assignment_cnf.push_back(tostring(*position) + " 0\n");
        else if(index->second == "0") PI_assignment_cnf.push_back("-" + tostring(*position) + " 0\n");
        position++;
    }
    PI_assignment_cnf.insert(PI_assignment_cnf.begin(), "c this is assign_PI\n");
    cnFile += PI_assignment_cnf;
    print_vector(cnFile, "cnFile");
}


void Oracle::solve(){
    cout << " start solving" << endl;

}
```

my makefile is:

```
##
##  Template makefile for Standard, Profile, Debug, Release, and Release-static versions
##
##    eg: "make rs" for a statically linked release version.
##        "make d"  for a debug version (no optimizations).
##        "make"    for the standard version (optimized, but with debug information and assertions active)

PWD        = $(shell pwd)
EXEC      ?= $(notdir $(PWD))

CSRCS      = $(wildcard $(PWD)/*.cc) 
DSRCS      = $(foreach dir, $(DEPDIR), $(filter-out $(MROOT)/$(dir)/Main.cc, $(wildcard $(MROOT)/$(dir)/*.cc)))
CHDRS      = $(wildcard $(PWD)/*.h)
COBJS      = $(CSRCS:.cc=.o) $(DSRCS:.cc=.o)

PCOBJS     = $(addsuffix p,  $(COBJS))
DCOBJS     = $(addsuffix d,  $(COBJS))
RCOBJS     = $(addsuffix r,  $(COBJS))


CXX       ?= g++ 
CFLAGS    ?= -Wall -Wno-parentheses -std=c++11 
LFLAGS    ?= -Wall

COPTIMIZE ?= -O3

CFLAGS    += -I$(MROOT) -D __STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -D __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS
LFLAGS    += -lz

.PHONY : s p d r rs clean 

s:  $(EXEC)
p:  $(EXEC)_profile
d:  $(EXEC)_debug
r:  $(EXEC)_release
rs: $(EXEC)_static

libs:   lib$(LIB)_standard.a
libp:   lib$(LIB)_profile.a
libd:   lib$(LIB)_debug.a
libr:   lib$(LIB)_release.a

## Compile options
%.o:            CFLAGS +=$(COPTIMIZE) -g -D DEBUG
%.op:           CFLAGS +=$(COPTIMIZE) -pg -g -D NDEBUG
%.od:           CFLAGS +=-O0 -g -D DEBUG
%.or:           CFLAGS +=$(COPTIMIZE) -g -D NDEBUG

## Link options
$(EXEC):        LFLAGS += -g
$(EXEC)_profile:    LFLAGS += -g -pg
$(EXEC)_debug:      LFLAGS += -g
#$(EXEC)_release:   LFLAGS += ...
$(EXEC)_static:     LFLAGS += --static

## Dependencies
$(EXEC):        $(COBJS)
$(EXEC)_profile:    $(PCOBJS)
$(EXEC)_debug:      $(DCOBJS)
$(EXEC)_release:    $(RCOBJS)
$(EXEC)_static:     $(RCOBJS)

lib$(LIB)_standard.a:   $(filter-out */Main.o,  $(COBJS))
lib$(LIB)_profile.a:    $(filter-out */Main.op, $(PCOBJS))
lib$(LIB)_debug.a:  $(filter-out */Main.od, $(DCOBJS))
lib$(LIB)_release.a:    $(filter-out */Main.or, $(RCOBJS))


## Build rule
%.o %.op %.od %.or: %.cc
    @echo Compiling: $(subst $(MROOT)/,,$@)
    @$(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

## Linking rules (standard/profile/debug/release)
$(EXEC) $(EXEC)_profile $(EXEC)_debug $(EXEC)_release $(EXEC)_static:
    @echo Linking: "$@ ( $(foreach f,$^,$(subst $(MROOT)/,,$f)) )"
    @$(CXX) $^ $(LFLAGS) -o $@

## Library rules (standard/profile/debug/release)
lib$(LIB)_standard.a lib$(LIB)_profile.a lib$(LIB)_release.a lib$(LIB)_debug.a:
    @echo Making library: "$@ ( $(foreach f,$^,$(subst $(MROOT)/,,$f)) )"
    @$(AR) -rcsv $@ $^

## Library Soft Link rule:
libs libp libd libr:
    @echo "Making Soft Link: $^ -> lib$(LIB).a"
    @ln -sf $^ lib$(LIB).a

## Clean rule
clean:
    @rm -f $(EXEC) $(EXEC)_profile $(EXEC)_debug $(EXEC)_release $(EXEC)_static \
      $(COBJS) $(PCOBJS) $(DCOBJS) $(RCOBJS) *.core depend.mk 

## Make dependencies
depend.mk: $(CSRCS) $(CHDRS)
    @echo Making dependencies
    @$(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -I$(MROOT) \
       $(CSRCS) -MM | sed 's|\(.*\):|$(PWD)/\1 $(PWD)/\1r $(PWD)/\1d $(PWD)/\1p:|' > depend.mk
    @for dir in $(DEPDIR); do \
          if [ -r $(MROOT)/$${dir}/depend.mk ]; then \
          echo Depends on: $${dir}; \
          cat $(MROOT)/$${dir}/depend.mk >> depend.mk; \
          fi; \
      done

-include $(MROOT)/mtl/config.mk
-include depend.mk
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is due to `using namespace std;`. Don't do that, *ever*.

Some people say it's fine as long as it's not in a header file, but they are wrong, and your error is a great example.

In this case, you're accidentally referring to `std::hash`, which is a *class* template, so the `<>` cannot be omitted, unlike for function templates.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much, it solve my problem. Juts for a quick question, if there is a identifier that is common in several name spaces. Is there any priority to use, like first "using" first use? For example, hash is first declared in std and then Incre, and then it will the one in std rather than Incre's, is that correct?